# Laravel table relationship

Tags: php, database, laravel-4

I have 3 tables:

```
users
leads
users_leads
```

On `users` table:

```
---------------
-- id | name --
-- 1  | doe  --
-- 2  | joe  --
---------------
```

On `leads` table:

```
----------------
-- id | type  --
-- 1  | house --
-- 2  | condo --
-- 3  | house --
----------------
```

On `users_leads` table:

```
----------------------------
-- id | user_id | lead_id --
-- 1  | 1       | 1       --
-- 1  | 1       | 2       --
-- 1  | 2       | 3       --
----------------------------
```

Then I have my models:

```
User.php
Lead.php
UsersLead.php
```

On model/UsersLead.php

```
class UsersLead extends Eloquent {
   public function leads()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo('Lead');
   }
}
```

On model/Lead.php

```
class Lead extends Eloquent {
   public function userslead()
   {
      return $this->hasMany('UsersLead');
   }
}
```

Then I tried to run it:

```
$data = Lead::all()->userslead;
```

Laravel is throwing this error:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$userslead
```

how do I run the query using eloquent ORM. To get all lead that belongs to specific user?

Anyone can help? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need many to many relationship:

**In your User model:**

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function leads()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Lead');
    }

}
```

**In your Lead model:**

```
class Lead extends Eloquent {

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }

}
```

**Then from your controller:**
Utilize the many to many relationship.

```
$leads = User::find(1)->leads;
```

**Important:**

Three database tables are needed for this relationship: `users`, `leads`, and `lead_user`. The `lead_user` table is derived from the alphabetical order of the related model names, and should have `user_id` and `lead_id` columns.

Reference:

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many

**Iterate items**

```
foreach ($leads as $lead)
{
    dd($lead);
}
```

More info:

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables

Comment: how do i process the $leads into foreach() loop? @Anam

Comment: @justin, follow the link: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all user leads:

```
$data = Lead::with('userslead')->get();
```

In order to get data for specific user you should refer it by ID:

```
$data = Lead::find($id)->userslead;
```