# How do I get rows based on another table with Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have one table with profiles. In this table there is no way to know what user have access to each row.

```
CREATE TABLE `rw_profiles` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Then I have another table to link each user with a profile. This table can contain same `profile_id` but different `user_id` (many users can access same profile).

```
CREATE TABLE `rw_profile_access` (
 `profile_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 UNIQUE KEY `profile_access_profile_id_owner_unique` (`profile_id`,`owner`),
 KEY `profile_access_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `profile_access_profile_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`profile_id`) REFERENCES `rw_profiles` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `profile_access_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `rw_users` (`id`)
)
```

How do I list all profiles that a user has access too? Are you supposed to use the `with`-method?

Something like `$profiles = Profile::with('...')->get();`?

---

#### Update

As of now I'm joining the table.

```
$profiles = Profile::join('profile_access', function($query) use ($user) {
    $query
        ->on('profile_id', '=', 'profiles.id')
        ->on('user_id', '=', DB::raw($user['id']));
})->get(['profiles.*']);
```

That works. Is this the only way or can I do it without join?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the many-to-many relationship in your User and Profile models.  They need methods like:

```
class User {
    public function Profiles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Profile', 'rw_profile_access', 'user_id', 'profile_id');
    }
}

class Profile {
    public function Users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'rw_profile_access', 'profile_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

The parameters for Profiles() and Users() correspond to:

- Related model
- Pivot table
- Foreign key
- Foreign key

You can then query like this:

```
$users_with_their_profiles = User::with('profiles')->get();
$users_that_definitely_have_profiles = User::with('profiles')->has('profiles')->get();
```

The Laravel documentation explains this thoroughly at http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships.

Answer (score 0):

You can use many to many relationship.

[Laravel table relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20675904/laravel-table-relationship?answertab=votes#tab-top)

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables

**OR:**

Assume you have `ProfileAccess` model.

```
$profiles = ProfileAccess::with('profile')
               ->where('user_id', $user['id'] )
               ->get();

foreach($profiles as $profile) {
   dd($profile->profile->name);
}
```